# distinct() is not working

Tags: django

I'm trying to group duplicate values but it's not working. I've google many times and they point distinct() function. No matter what I do is not working. I try distinct() before in other queries (not mine) and it's working, now I'm using it, it's not working.

Here are my codes:

models.py

```
 class Transaction(models.Model):
    payee = models.CharField(
        max_length=255
        )
```

views.py

```
 transactions = Transaction.objects.values_list('payee', flat=True).distinct()
```

output:

```
 [u'YOUR LOCAL SUPERMARKET', 
  u'CITY OF SPRINGFIELD', 
  u'SPRINGFIELD WATER UTILITY', 
  u'DEPOSIT', 
  u'DEPOSIT']
```

Notice the output there is duplicate for `DEPOSIT`

Comment: In your `Transaction` model do you have any `Meta`, like `unique_together` ?

Comment: @limelights yes but it's ordering `ordering = ['-date', 'id']`. Is this the cause why it's not working?

Comment: @limelights I removed the ordering and it's working now. But is there a way to have both ordering and distinct()?

Comment: @limelights yes I solved my problem, thanks for the info I figure out now how to use both distinct() and ordering

Comment: Sweet :) I'll refrain from answering then :) https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct

Comment: You can leave the default ordering and disable it in the query by calling `order_by` with no params: `Transaction.objects.order_by().values_list('payee', flat=True).distinct()`

Comment: @Igor post the answer and I will give you points. I already solve my problem

Comment: @limelights you better answer also to have points

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you have defined an ordering the `distinct()` will take these fields into account when trying to do the SQL and thusly can return strange results.

You can therefore:

- either skip ordering,
- call an empty `order_by()` in your query,
- you can define what fields you want to have `distinct()` on.

So on your case the query would be

`Transaction.objects.order_by('payee').distinct('payee')`

this will disregard any ordering you might have and it will also be a bit more clearer to whats happening but this comes at the cost of only being available in PostGresSQL.

[Read more here in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct)